# is there a way to validate data by saying "variable != int"

Tags: java, if-statement, int, conditional-statements, validation

So this is basically what I want my code to say, as to avoid compile error's in the event that the user selects `"Tea"` instead of using the corresponding integer.

```
if(appSelection < 1 || appSelection > appetizersArray.length || appSelection != int)
```

the first two conditions are obviously to catch data that would be out of bounds, but I'm looking for a way to specify that the input needs to be an int.

If the only option is `try catch` just say so but I'm hoping there's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression. The lower case `\\d` matches digits and adding a plus means consecutive. So,

```
String regex = "\\d+";
String[] arr = { "Tea", "123" };
for (String str : arr) {
    if (str.matches(regex)) {
        System.out.printf("%s is all digits%n", str);
    } else {
        System.out.printf("%s is NOT all digits%n", str);
    }
}
```

Output is

```
Tea is NOT all digits
123 is all digits
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this command-line input? If so, you can use the Scanner class's nextInt method (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29). If it's coming from a web form, either your library should convert the value to an integer, in which case you already know it's an integer, or it's a string and you can call Integer.parseInt(String). Documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data comes in a String, well, a try/catch is the thing to use, or some function to check if the provided data is a valid integer, like this:

```
boolean isValidInt(String s) {
  try {
    Integer.parseInt(s);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Then you can say:

```
if(!isValidInt(appSelection)) someError();
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a Java-related question, `int` is a primitive. The operation you are referring to has a operator: `instanceof`. Unfortunately, it does not work for primitive data types. In order to use this you have to use a wrapper class (i.e `Integer`).  So:

```
int x = 1;
if (x instanceof Integer) { // compilation error }
```

Unfortunately, autoboxing does not work for this.  What you can do is the following:

```
String value = ???;  // ??? represents some unknown string value.
```

Later on, you can try to convert that String value to an Integer value:

```
try
{
    Integer x = new Integer(str);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    // The exception will be thrown if the string does not represent a numeric value. For example: a34bc
}
```

If the instantiation of variable x succeeds, it will hold a numeric value.  Because of Java unboxing mechanism, you will be able to pass 'x' to some method that takes a primitive `int`.  For example:

```
try
{
    Integer x = new Integer(str);
    int result = addThisValue(x);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {// Do something }
...
public int addThisValue(int value) {...}
```

You will be able to pass variable `x` to that method safely.